# Ler quantidade ate chegar em -1

Tags: c

eu empaquei nesse exercicio da facu:

FAZER um programa com um método ( exercicio06 ) para:

ler dois valores inteiros (a) e (b) do teclado,
ler outros valores inteiros do teclado, um por vez,
até que o último valor seja igual a (-1).
para todos os valores no intervalo aberto ]a:b[;
calcular e mostrar a soma dos quadrados dos inversos (1/x2
).
DICA: Evitar divisão por zero mediante uso de alternativa dupla.

A minha entrada é essa,porem ao compilar quando chega no -1,ele ja termina:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a minha saida é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguem puder ajudar em alguma coisa,nem sei se esta correto da forma que fiz o calculo tbm… Preciso de alguma ajuda,

valeu galera.

Comment: não coloque imagem nas perguntas, coloque apenas texto, porque se alguém testar seu código vai ter que digitar ele todo, não dá para copiar e colar!

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo, é que você vai lendo os números e, depois que o -1 é encontrado, sai do `while`. Nesse momento, o seu `x` está valendo 0 e não cai dentro do `if`, por isso seu código termina.

O exercício pede algo um pouco diferente do que você está fazendo também. A soma dos inversos dos quadrados, seria ir somando todos os inversos dos quadrados dos números dentro do intervalo especificado.

Ex:

```
a = 5
b = 8

Números digitados: 1 3 6 7 8 10 -1

Resultado = 1/(6^2) + 1/(7^2) + 1/(8^2)

Como somente 6, 7 e 8 estão no intervalo entre 5 e 8, somente os seus inversos são calculados
```

O que eu recomendaria é você ir lendo os números e, cada vez que ler um, verifica se ele está no intervalo especificado e, se estiver, soma o inverso do quadrado dele no resultado. Quando você ler o `-1`, sai do laço e imprime o resultado na tela.

Comment: Ele pode simplesmente utilizar o `while` em vez do `do...while` para fazer a verificação do `-1` antes de executar o restante do código, certo?

Comment: Sim, mas o código dela está fazendo o cálculo errado, então só fazer isso não resolveria. A idéia que eu quis passar na resposta é pra seguir mais ou menos nessa linha, mas corrigindo o cálculo e sem dar a resposta em si :)